# operating with group of indexes of an array without using loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, grouping, operation

I have an array with data like below:

```
$data=array(
    array(1,1),
    array(1,2),
    array(1,3),
    array(1,4),
    array(1,5),
    array(1,6),
    array(1,7)
);
```

And I want to apply some operands to group of data, for example

**(pseudo-code)**

```
// get all indexes , after the second index of each index
$d = $data[all indexes][1] /10 ; //devided by 10


// multiple the second index of first to fifteenth indexes by 2
$d2=$data[0-15][1] * 2;
```

I know I can use foreach or any other loops , but i'm looking for a better way .

Comment: And you want to do what?

Comment: I think the OP forgot to add the rest of the question

Comment: excuse me , having some problem with posting data , and i'v just edited it.

Comment: Do you want to get the sum of values divided by 10/ multiplied by 2?

Comment: no , the same data as it's been , but just devide by e.g 10 , output must be an aray just like input

Comment: @user3365425 Add output of desired result

Comment: @user3365425 Why are loops bad?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't really get why you don't want to use loops, but if it makes you feel better you can use a "loop in disguise"!

PHP offers some functions to perform a repetitive task in an array, for example:

- [**arrray_map**](http://pt2.php.net/array_map) - Keeps the base array intact
- [**array_walk**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) - Changes the base array

---

## Example with array_map

**Code**

```
$newData = array_map (function($subArray)
{
    return $subArray[1] / 10;
}, $data);
```

**output**

```
array (size=7)
  0 => float 0.1
  1 => float 0.2
  2 => float 0.3
  3 => float 0.4
  4 => float 0.5
  5 => float 0.6
  6 => float 0.7
```

---

**Answer to OP comment:**

If it's a performance problem, then array_map is actually slower than foreach or for loops.

I don't think PHP has built in library to deal with matrices operations. However, a quick search in PEAR revealed this extension:

http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Matrix

I've never used so I don't know if it's any good, and the package isn't maintained anymore

Comment: Thank you , it's a good way , but this way  like other loops takes time to walk over all data of an array , i want to know does PHP have a better way to treat arrays like matrix in matlab ?

Comment: @user3365425 I don't think PHP has any built in library specific to matrices, but check http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Matrix